# In Scala REPL, how to discard partly written multi-line command?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

On Unix Shell terminal, you can discard a typed command just by typing ctrl-c.
Is there a way to discard a typed command on Scala REPL?

Comment: one neat trick that works for me: hit the Up button (replaces whatever you typed with previous executed line) and then the Down button (replaces previous line with, well, nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're writing an unfinished block you can enter two blank lines and the REPL will then skip your command and start a new one.

You may then still use up buttons to retrieve the lines you want to continue with in the new command.

Answer (score 5):

`Ctrl-C` still works but it would exit the Scala REPL, which is probably not what you prefer.

A couple of cases:

1. If you're in the middle of a single-line command, you can hit `Up` button then `Down` to an empty command line.
2. If you're in the middle of a multi-line command and the command is incomplete, you can simply hit `return` a couple of times to let the REPL interpret the consecutive blank lines as intention to start a new command.  But, in case you worry about whatever you've typed might get executed, safest way would still be to hit `Ctrl-C`.